# Django, long filter query

Tags: mysql, django, request

I cant understand why it works like this, for example:

Query1

```
   Q(
                        Q(groups__name=CONST_DEALER) &
                        Q(additional_info__address__district=address.district)
                    )
```

**lead time: 2sec**

Query2

```
    Q(Q(Q(groups__name=CONST_SELLER) | Q(groups__name=CONST_GROWER)) 
&                     Q(minor_user__major__additional_info__address__district=address.district)
                    )
```

**lead time: 2sec**

but when I unites them(i need to unites them)

```
Q(
                Q(
                    Q(groups__name=CONST_DEALER) &
                    Q(additional_info__address__district=address.district)
                ) |
                Q(
                    Q(Q(groups__name=CONST_SELLER) | Q(groups__name=CONST_GROWER)) &
                    Q(minor_user__major__additional_info__address__district=address.district)
                )
            )
```

**lead time: 80sec!!!!!!**

tell me how to make a quick request

Comment: You here make `JOIN`s on different tables, so by combining these, you have now make multiple `JOIN`s resulting in a *huge* result table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you make here several `JOIN`s: on `groups`, `additional_info`, and `minor_user__major`, etc. The result is that by combining those, you "stack" `JOIN`s, and therefore the table that arises from these `JOIN`s is quite huge.

You can just make a union query to avoid this, like:

```
qs1 = MyModel.objects.filter(
    groups__name=CONST_DEALER,
    additional_info__address__district=address.district
)
qs2 = MyModel.objects.filter(
     Q(groups__name=CONST_SELLER) | Q(groups__name=CONST_GROWER),                 
     minor_user__major__additional_info__address__district=address.district
)

query = qs1.union(qs2)
```

The queries `qs1` and `qs2` are *not* evaluated (unless you do this yourself of course), we just use these to construct the end `query`.